# how to import a python class's moudle?

Tags: python

I have this main.py, in it:

```
import uuid
class tools(object):
  def generate_uuid(self):
    return self.uuid.uuid4()
```

in my calling program callmain.py, I have

```
import main
result = main.tool.generate_uuid()
print ("result")
```

if I run my callmain.py: I get

> "TypeError: generate_uuid() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'self'

if I add self to the line 
    `result = main.tool.generate_uuid(self):` I get

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How to fix this? thank for help.

Comment: Why does this `tools` class exist?

Comment: 1. Typo in the title (moudle) 2. The class is called 'tools', not 'tool', 3. You need to create an object before calling an instance method 4. Classes are usually capitalised 5. Self is passed explicitly to instance methods

Comment: I am learning how to use python import. tools actually contain many other module. I am just learning its behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you should make a object from your class first. then call your sub function like this:

```
import main
result = tools()
result.generate_uuid()
print(result) # "result" is a string! you should just call result without any "".
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the module of a class you have to create an instance of that class first and call if from that instance, that way the self argument is passed a valid reference to an instance of that class. For example:

```
import main

tools_instance = main.tools()
result = tools_instance.generate_uuid()
```

The style of importing shown in your question looks like a package. In packages a folder of python files `__init__.py` can be arranged in a particular way, documented here [Python Packages](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/import.html#packages). An example from the docs

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    one/
        __init__.py
    two/
        __init__.py
    three/
        __init__.py
```

So an package of the format

```
main/
    __init__.py
    tools/
        __init__.py # Add function 'generate_uuid' in this file
```

Could be utilized as follow:

```
import main

result = main.tools.generate_uuid()
print(result)
```